# Правильная остановка/запуск службы windows

Tags: c#, winforms, службы

Нашёл на просторах интернета такой код:

```
private static ServiceController ser { get; set; }
using (ser = new ServiceController("MpsSvc")) 
{
       ser.Start();
       label.Visible = true;
       label.Text = "Служба запущена!";
       ser.Close();
}
```

Иногда работает, иногда нет.

Можно ли к выше указанному коду прикрутить проверку существования службы + проверку запуска службы ( если служба остановлена запустить)

Нужно ли использовать `get;set;` для таких целей?

---

Переделал так, поправьте если не правильно)

```
 private void StopService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var serviceController = new ServiceController("sevice"))
            {
                if (CheckService.CheckIfServiceExists("sevice"))
                {
                    serviceController.Stop();
                    serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
                    label.Visible = true;
                    label2.Text = "Служба остановлена";
                    StopService.Visible = false;
                    StartService.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

1-й раз проходит нормально, следующий пишет что службу не удалось остановить/запустить ( хотя перед остановкой служба работает )

С чем это связано?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы в любой момент можете проверить статус службы с помощью [`ServiceController.Status`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.status(v=vs.110).aspx)

Для проверки существования службы получайте список существующих служб и проверяйте присутсвие требуемой вами службы в этом списке:

```
public bool CheckIfServiceExists(string serviceName)
{
    var services = ServiceController.GetServices();
    return services.Any(s => s.ServiceName == serviceName);
}
```

> Нужно ли использовать get;set; для таких целей?

Вопрос неясен. На вашем месте я бы вообще убрал это свойство и оформил бы это в виде локальной переменной.

Для проверки действительно ли запустился/остановился сервис используйте [`ServiceController.WaitForStatus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w52kaf2y(v=vs.110).aspx) метод. Передавайте `ServiceControllerStatus.Running` для ожидания старта сервиса или `ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped` для ожидания остановки сервиса после вызова функций `ServiceController.Start()` и `ServiceController.Stop()` соответсвенно.

Пример старта сервиса:

```
using(var serviceController = new ServiceController(ИмяСервиса))
{
    serviceController.Start();
    serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
}
```

Comment: В виде локальной переменной?

Comment: А что вам мешает это сделать? Зачем вам держать ее как приватное свойство класса, тем более когда вы ее диспозаете?

Comment: Добавил пример старта сервиса. Учитите, что `serviceController.WaitForStatus()` может быть долгим процессом, поэтому я бы советовал предварительно обернуть метод в таску.

Comment: А если добавить список служб в `List<string>`, и после как использовать? Имею ввиду требуется ли `WaitForStatus` допустим я хочу остановить службы ( список служб ) ?